# Modal popup auto scrolls down

Tags: html, css

I have a modal popup where it warns users that we use cookies (among other modals). When the accept button is pressed it creates a cookie and will prevent the user from seeing the modal again for a while. When the modal is not showing the page is just fine, but when it popups the page automatically scrolls about 20% down and it annoys me.

heres the modal:

```
<div class="modal-background">
<form action="/etc/set_cookie.php" method="post">
  <div id="modal">
    <div class="modalconent tabs">
        <fieldset>
        <span class="close">×</span>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Cookies</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We use cookies to improve your experience</h3>
             <iframe style="width:100%; height:80px;" src="/etc/txt/cookies.php" ></iframe><br />
           <input type="submit" name="cookie" value="Accept" id="button" class="btn fr" style="width:180px; padding:10px;" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>


<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
    };
};





// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

and the css:

```
/* Modal
************************************************** */
.modal-background {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:90;
}

#modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    top:15%;
}
.modalconent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.6s    
}


.close {
    color:#475f93;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}



/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}
```

I have noticed that when removing the `#modal { top:15%; }` the page only scrolls down about 20px, but then the modal is at wrong place

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zdmy91a4/)**

Comment: Please add fiddle example

Comment: wouldn't you want your modal to have `position:fixed`?

Comment: you should post a better example since your current code doesn't demonstrate the problem well. The problem you mention is likely because of position/placement issue with your css.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I havent thought off adding position fixed. But what do you mean with "position/placement issue with your css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[Here is codepen.io example](http://codepen.io/valeri879/pen/xEyoBb)

```js
$(".modal-background, .modal-close").on("click", function(){
  $(".modal-container, .modal-background").hide();
});
```

```css
.modal-background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.modal-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.modal-container .modal-close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
.modal-container .modal-header {
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  background: #333;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
.modal-container .modal-info {
  padding: 25px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.modal-container .button-container {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.modal-container .button-container button {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-background"></div>
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-header">cookies <i class="modal-close">x</i></div>
  <div class="modal-info">
    We use cookies to improve your experience
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button type="submit">accept</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nope, still have the same problem where the page scrollss down

Comment: I have turned error reporting off and use no echo in the php that the modal uses, only set cookie via php when the accept button is pressed. The problem just recently started so i belive it has something todo with the  css or html

Comment: is it possible to use JS to force top onload?

Comment: try to add class on `body` tag .`modal-open` when modal is open and use this `css` for `body.modal-open{overflow:hidden};`